# Where is "Row total" defined in the Magento code?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, sales-order

On the `sales order view` screen in the backend of `Magento 1.9`, the products are listed as well as any discounts, GST etc. I need to know how this row total figure is calculated but am having trouble finding the file where this figure is calculated.

Does anyone know what file the calculation for "`Row Total`" is defined?

Comment: you want it on frontend or backend.?

Comment: I need to grab the value that is on the backend sales order view screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the template path hints for admin by following the below link - http://www.classyllama.com/blog/enable-templateblock-hints-in-admin-panel

The row total is calculated from this file

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml
```